# Finding the CPT archive template source

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I've created a CPT named `kindergarten` by a plugin ; 
I was able to see the archive page of this custom post type with its posts;
When I was using Elementor for changing the template of this post type, I don't know what happened that I see a message that there is no posts for that; like this:
[image]

I've created a `archive-kindergarten.php` for test, But I don't see any change.
How can I find what is the source for this CPT template?
How can I force Wordpress to use elementor template as an archive template for this post type?
(I have to mention that posts work perfectly but archive page doesn't )

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is what is being ask, but possibly it is.

if we add the woocommerce theme support on function.php like so

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

we can copy the archive-product.php  from the woocommerce plugin to our theme, than we can edit and use that file, the archive-product.php set the page that show the products by category that has a loop to each individual product, and each product presented is set  on the page content-product.php, that can also be copied to our theme and edit at our wish, this way even if woocommerce gets an update we are fine. However this should be made in a child_theme, because if the theme gets updated can override this files or even who knows delete them.

It's possible also to create a template and use it on a page.